# How to give permission to spring application running under tomcat to write on another user directory

Tags: java, linux, spring-mvc, tomcat, permissions

On one of my VPS,
I have tomcat server on `/opt/tomcat` with user `tomcat:tomcat`,
I have a host which runs spring application to serve the sub domain of user `someuser`
i.e  http://crm.someuser.com

Now I need to write files/images to that folder/directory i.e  `/home/someuser/crm.someuser.com`,
Whenever I try to write file, permission denied exception occur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File system permission problem.

Short answer, grant write permissions on the target folder by changing the folder permissions using **chmod** linux command

e.g.

**chmod ugoa+w /home/someuser/crm.someuser.com**

Of course you have to be the owner of that folder, if not at least you have sudo capabilities so you can execute the chmod command on that folder.

**sudo ugoa+w /home/someuser/crm.someuser.com**

Doing a list command on the folder

```
ls -alh
-rw-r--r--  1 user user  675 Mar  14  2017 /home/someuser/crm.someuser.com
```

After executing the chmod command, the write permissions should show something like

```
ls -alh
-rw-rw-rw-  1 user user  675 Mar  14  2017 /home/someuser/crm.someuser.com
```

You will notice rw (meaing read and write permissions) for that folder

Long answer, the answer above will allow any user to write to that folder since it has write permission for user, group and others. A good way is only allow users who belongs to a group to be able to write to that folder.

E.g. Depending on your use case, you may want to add that user to the tomcat group and change the owner of the folder to tomcat. Then grant write permission to the tomcat group to that folder. This way only users belonging to tomcat can write to that folder.

Here is the updated solution.

Create a new group that will have permission to write to those folders.

```
groupadd YOURGROUP
```

Change the group owner for each of those folders. (You can retain the current owner as is and modify only the group by passing the same owner in the command)

```
sudo chown someuser:YOURGROUP /home/someuser/crm.someuser.com
```

Change the permission of that folder so that YOURGROUP will have read/write capabilities

```
sudo chmod g+rw /home/someuser/crm.someuser.com
```

Lastly, add tomcat to that group. So tomcat will have read/write capabilities to those folder.

```
sudo usermod -a -G YOURGROUP tomcat
```

Where tomcat is the valid user used by tomcat (others use tomcat7, you need to check the actual username of tomcat on your system)

Comment: Long Answer suits my case very well as it need to be secure also.
But i am confused with the line.
grant write permission to the tomcat group to that folder.
You mean to say give write permission to that folder for group. ie chmod g+w thatfolder
Now one doubt.
Since by default subdomain folder owe ownership with owner:nobody.
Would not it be problem on future?

Comment: ok, if you wanted it secure way, you can certainly create a group that will have write permission to those folder. I am not sure how each domain/user is managed but given what you have provided, I will create a group regardless of domain who will own that folder. Change the group owner to owner:GROUP where group is the new group defined. you can do it using chown command. Then set the writer permission to g+w as you have mentioned so that anyone who belongs to the GROUP will be able to write to those folder. Then finally, add tomcat as part of that group.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not related to Spring app; you just only set read, write permissions for tomcat user on that folder. You can try with: setfacl command (http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/en/man1/setfacl.1.html) or something like this. E.x:

```
setfacl -m u:tomcat:rw /home/someuser/crm.someuser.com
```

Hope that it helps you.

Comment: i have done the same as mentioned and also check with getfacl but doesnot work.
If this works,it would be best solution for me.
Here is link of img
http://imgur.com/2lYBu5c

Answer (score 0):

This work for me:

```
public Path getPathdoc(String filename) {
    //return Paths.get(UPLOADS_FOLDER).resolve(filename).toAbsolutePath();
    return Paths.get("/var/lib/mysql-files").resolve(filename).toAbsolutePath();
}
```

Here you set all permission with: "rwxrwxrwx"

```
 @Override
    public String copydoc(MultipartFile file) throws IOException {
        String uniqueFilename = file.getOriginalFilename();
        Path rootPath = getPathdoc(uniqueFilename);
        log.info("rootPath: " + rootPath);
        Files.copy(file.getInputStream(), rootPath);
        Files.setPosixFilePermissions(getPath(uniqueFilename), PosixFilePermissions.fromString("rwxrwxrwx"));
        return uniqueFilename;
    }
```